# Awesomium: what is Dart?

Tags: dart, awesomium

There's [an option to enable Dart](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/P_Awesomium_Core_WebPreferences_Dart.htm) in Awesomium's preferences (true by default). But the documentation is not very explicit about it. Does anybody know what it is for? What would be the benefits / cons to turn it on?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_(programming_language)

Comment: @HongOoi OK! So nothing to do with Awesomium itself. Then unless I want support for Dart on my pages, there's no point enabling it. Consider posting an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This options to provide Dart language. With this language you can write your awesome html application more fast then with JS, more maintable. And Dart can work two times faster than JS.

Awesomium is a intergable browser, and if you want to use it with own html applications you can use Dart language to develop it and get benefits I have wrote before.

Moreover, I guess Awesomium is a Chrome's fork and in this case you can write in Dart not html application only but Chrome extensions too!